# When you register an assembly in SQL Server using CREATE ASSEMBLY - where does SQL Server store it?

Tags: sql-server, clr

When you register an assembly in SQL Server using CREATE ASSEMBLY - where does SQL Server store it?

e.g. the following statement registers an assembly with SQL SERVER but I want to know where this is stored by SQL SERVER

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [YaddyYaddy]
   FROM 'C:\YaddyYaddy.dll'
   WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE; 
GO
```

Comment: Not sure how precisely you want to know - but rest assured, the assemblies are stored **inside** the database, e.g. they'll be backed up, transported and restored together with the other db objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marc_s gave the best answer. See below

> Not sure how precisely you want to
>   know - but rest assured, the
>   assemblies are stored inside the
>   database, e.g. they'll be backed up,
>   transported and restored together with
>   the other db objects

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that the actual uploaded DLL code can be found in **sys.assembly_files**, within the database that the assembly was loaded into.

Check out sys.assemblies, sys.assembly_files, and sys.assembly_modules (and follow the object_id links to sys.objects) for details on the stored assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

Using SSMS, I can see them in the Object Explorer tree under db\programmability\assemblies

Comment: Yes so can I but I wanted to know where they are stored. marc_s comment tells me as much as I need to know.

Answer (score 1):

It stored in below hierarchy in datatabse: 
"Server Name" > Databases > "Your Dtabase Name" > Programmability > Assemblies.

And you can delete it and it's dependencies as below :

`DROP function  Function1_Name;
 DROP function  Function2_Name;
 DROP ASSEMBLY Assembly_Name;`